# how to remove duplicate values from nested array

Tags: angular

How do I remove duplicate SubjectName from nested array.

In Data.SubjectInfo Array Many Subject Names are Duplicated I want shows only single SubjectName per Class.

I have two *ngFor in table, one getting ClassName and details and the second ngFor is used for Subjects List and details.

I have tried over the last two days but with no success. I have Googled and tried many examples but now I am posting my question in my case I want remove only duplicate subjects from inner dynamic Array. Can anyone help me with this? I would highly appreciate it.

```
var ss= Array.from(new Set(subjectlist.map(team => team._id.SubjectName)));

<table class="table">
    <tr  *ngFor="let data of arrayList">
        <th class=" text-white bg-success2" (click)="deleteConfirm(data,subjects)">{{ data.ClassId.ClassName }}</th>
        <td *ngFor="let subjects of data.SubjectInfo"><button  type="button"  class="btn btn-primary  btn-block btn-sm"> {{subjects._id.SubjectName}}</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JSON values:

```
[{  "IsShow": true,
        "_id": "5e2ad954940e901f4c62bc71",
        "SubjectInfo": [{
            "Day": "Monday",
            "Time": "12:25",
            "_id": {
                "IsShow": true,
                "_id": "5e2197cfc7a8b050dccf69ce",
                "SubjectName": "English",
                "Created": "2020-01-17T11:17:35.845Z",
                "Updated": "2020-01-17T11:17:35.845Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        }, {
            "Day": "Monday",
            "Time": "09:00",
            "_id": {
                "IsShow": true,
                "_id": "5e2198ba17f6a364483b02ab",
                "SubjectName": "Urdu",
                "Created": "2020-01-17T11:21:30.445Z",
                "Updated": "2020-01-17T11:21:30.445Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        }, {
            "Day": "Tuesday",
            "Time": "00:11",
            "_id": {
                "IsShow": true,
                "_id": "5e2197cfc7a8b050dccf69ce",
                "SubjectName": "English",
                "Created": "2020-01-17T11:17:35.845Z",
                "Updated": "2020-01-17T11:17:35.845Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        }, {
            "Day": "Wednesday",
            "Time": "09:10",
            "_id": {
                "IsShow": true,
                "_id": "5e2197cfc7a8b050dccf69ce",
                "SubjectName": "English",
                "Created": "2020-01-17T11:17:35.845Z",
                "Updated": "2020-01-17T11:17:35.845Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        }, {
            "Day": "Monday",
            "Time": "12:11",
            "_id": {
                "IsShow": true,
                "_id": "5e2198c217f6a364483b02ad",
                "SubjectName": "Maths",
                "Created": "2020-01-17T11:21:38.394Z",
                "Updated": "2020-01-17T11:21:38.394Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        }, {
            "Day": "Tuesday",
            "Time": "11:11",
            "_id": {
                "IsShow": true,
                "_id": "5e2558df3a8e794230eb49d6",
                "SubjectName": "Chemistry",
                "Created": "2020-01-20T07:38:07.499Z",
                "Updated": "2020-01-20T07:38:07.499Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        }, {
            "Day": "Tuesday",
            "Time": "11:11",
            "_id": {
                "IsShow": true,
                "_id": "5e2198ba17f6a364483b02ab",
                "SubjectName": "Urdu",
                "Created": "2020-01-17T11:21:30.445Z",
                "Updated": "2020-01-17T11:21:30.445Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        }],
        "Created": "2020-01-24T11:47:32.070Z",
        "Updated": "2020-01-24T11:47:32.070Z",
        "ClassId": {
            "IsShow": true,
            "_id": "5e2197b5ee8eb24f58bae63e",
            "ClassName": "Class 1",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "__v": 0

    }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lodash : https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash

```
this.arrayList.forEach((onearray: any) => {
       onearray.SubjectInfo = _uniqBy(onearray.SubjectInfo, (x) => x._id.SubjectName);
    });
```

Working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-en9pf3